# MySQL: alter table foo alter column binary(6) --- column is presently int(5)

Tags: mysql, alter

Is it possible to convert an integer column in MySQL into a binary column and preserve the data?
I want to just convert it byte for byte, as you could see in a C union.

Addendum: I tried this:

alter table foo change colname colname binary(6);

...however what this does is convert the string representation of the int(5) into a binary.
I want to convert the underlying integer bytes into the binary.

Is there a way to do this?

Thus for instance if the integer was 100, I want the binary to be 0x64 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0 0x0.

Thanks.

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE a (
'binary_field' BINARY(6) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE b (
'int_field' INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO b
SELECT CONVERT(binary_field, UNSIGNED) FROM a
```

or You can also use SIGNED

Comment: You got the direction wrong. I want to go from int to binary. But I tried your method and the effect is the same.